# Laravel 4 many to many get all data from both tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have tables: users, resources and pivot table user_resources.

users

- id
- username

etc.

resources

- id
- resource_name

etc.

user_resources

- id
- user_id
- resource_id

User model:

```
class Resources extends Eloquent {

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_resources');
    }
}
```

and resource model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function resources() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Resource', 'user_resources');
    }
}
```

How can I get all of the users and all of the resources that belongs to the users.

Answer (score 7):

Probably you just have to:

```
$everything = User::with('resources')->get();
```